# Launching a simple python script on an AWS ray cluster with docker

Tags: amazon-ec2, multiprocessing, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, ray

I am finding it incredibly difficult to follow rays guidelines to running a docker image on a ray cluster in order to execute a python script. I am finding a lack of simple working examples.

So I have the simplest docker file:

```
FROM rayproject/ray
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
CMD ["step_1.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

I use this to create can image and push this to docker hub. ("myimage" is just an example)

```
docker build -t myimage .   
docker push myimage
```

"step_1.py" just prints hello every second for 200 seconds:

```
import time
for i in range(200):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("hello")
```

This is my config.yaml. again very simple:

```
cluster_name: simple-1

min_workers: 0
max_workers: 2

docker:
    image: "myimage"    
    container_name: "my_simple_docker_container"
    pull_before_run: True

idle_timeout_minutes: 5

provider:
    type: aws
    region: eu-west-2
    availability_zone: eu-west-2a

file_mounts_sync_continuously: False



auth:
    ssh_user: ubuntu
    ssh_private_key: /home/user/.ssh/aws_ubuntu_test.pem
head_node:
    InstanceType: c5.2xlarge
    ImageId: ami-xxxxx826a6b31fd2c
    KeyName: aws_ubuntu_test

    BlockDeviceMappings:
      - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
        Ebs:
          VolumeSize: 200

worker_nodes:
   InstanceType: c5.2xlarge
   ImageId: ami-xxxxx826a6b31fd2c
   KeyName: aws_ubuntu_test
   InstanceMarketOptions:
        MarketType: spot

head_setup_commands:
    - pip install boto3==1.4.8

worker_setup_commands:  []

head_start_ray_commands:
    - ray stop
    - ulimit -n 65536; ray start --head --port=6379 --object-manager-port=8076 --autoscaling-config=~/ray_bootstrap_config.yaml

worker_start_ray_commands:
    - ray stop
    - ulimit -n 65536; ray start --address=$RAY_HEAD_IP:6379 --object-manager-port=8076
```

I hit in the terminal:

```
ray up simple1.yaml:
```

and this error every time:

```
shared connection to x.x.xx.119 closed.
"docker cp" requires exactly 2 arguments.
See 'docker cp --help'.

Usage:  docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
        docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH

Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem
Shared connection to x.x.xx.119 closed.
```

Just to add the docker image will run on any other remote machine just fine, just not on the the ray cluster.

If someone could please help me, I would be eternally grateful, and I will even promise to add a tutorial on medium after my struggles.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue might be around using `ENTRYPOINT`. The Ray ClusterLauncher starts docker using a command roughly like:

```
docker run --rm --name <NAME> -d -it --net=host <image_name> bash
```

When I ran `docker build -t myimage .`  and then ran `docker run --rm -it myimage bash`, Docker errored with:

```
python3: can't open file 'bash': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: this worked. The issue i'm having now is that I cannot see the output of the docker container. do you know where I might find this?